# An error using "Positioning" package to place the titles of a hexagon and a pentagon

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following `tikzpicture` environment, I have a hexagon and a pentagon aligned along their horizontal axes of symmetry. (In the hexagon, the vertex `A` is furthest to the right, the vertex `B` is the lowest vertex, vertices `C` and `E` are furthest to the left, `D` is the vertex towards the center, and `F` is the highest vertex. Similar labeling for the pentagon.) There are two aspects that are not right. The title for the pentagon is on itself. `E` is the highest vertex on the pentagon, and I use the command `\node[font=\bfseries, above=of E -| {$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$}] (title) {A convex set};` to place the title.  Why is the title not placed above the pentagon?  Also, why is the `tikzpicture` flush against the right margin?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance= 3mm and 0mm]

%A hexagon - a set that is not convex - is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (O) at (-5,0);

\path[name path=x-axis] (A) -- (O);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_-1] (-5,-1) -- (0,-1);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_1] (-5,1) -- (0,1);

\coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (C') at ($(B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_BC] (B) -- (C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_BC and horizontal_line_at_-1, by={C}}];
\draw (B) -- (C);

\coordinate (D') at ($(C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_CD] (C) -- (D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_CD and x-axis, by={D}}];
\draw (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E') at ($(D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_DE] (D) -- (E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_DE and horizontal_line_at_1, by={E}}];
\draw (D) -- (E);

\coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (E) -- (F);
\draw (A) -- (F);


%Points P and Q in the hexagon are plotted. Line segment $\overline{PQ}$ is not contained in the
%hexagon.
\coordinate (P) at (-4,0.75);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (Q) at (-4,-0.75);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (Q);
%Points P and Q are labeled.
\coordinate (label_for_P) at ($(P)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);
\node at (label_for_P){$P$};
\coordinate (label_for_Q) at ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(P)$);
\node at (label_for_Q){$Q$};

%Title for hexagon is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries,align=center,above=of F -| {$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$}] (title) {A set that is \\ not convex};


%A convex pentagon is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=6cm}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (O) at (-5,0);

\path[name path=x-axis] (A) -- (O);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_-1] (-5,-1) -- (0,-1);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_1] (-5,1) -- (0,1);

\coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (C') at ($(B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_BC] (B) -- (C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_BC and horizontal_line_at_-1, by={C}}];
\draw (B) -- (C);

\coordinate (D') at ($(C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_CD] (C) -- (D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_CD and x-axis, by={D}}];
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E') at ($(D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_DE] (D) -- (E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_DE and horizontal_line_at_1, by={E}}];
\draw[dashed] (D) -- (E);

\draw (C) -- (E);

\coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (E) -- (F);
\draw (A) -- (F);

%Title for pentagon is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries, above=of E -| {$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$}] (title) {A convex set};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

> Why is the title not placed above the pentagon?

Because point `F` is highest and not `E`.

> why is the tikzpicture flush against the right margin?

That is because you are setting `\hspace*{\fill}`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\noindent %\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance= 3mm and 0mm]

%A hexagon - a set that is not convex - is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (O) at (-5,0);

\path[name path=x-axis] (A) -- (O);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_-1] (-5,-1) -- (0,-1);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_1] (-5,1) -- (0,1);

\coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (C') at ($(B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_BC] (B) -- (C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_BC and horizontal_line_at_-1, by={C}}];
\draw (B) -- (C);

\coordinate (D') at ($(C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_CD] (C) -- (D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_CD and x-axis, by={D}}];
\draw (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E') at ($(D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_DE] (D) -- (E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_DE and horizontal_line_at_1, by={E}}];
\draw (D) -- (E);

\coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (E) -- (F);
\draw (A) -- (F);


%Points P and Q in the hexagon are plotted. Line segment $\overline{PQ}$ is not contained in the
%hexagon.
\coordinate (P) at (-4,0.75);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (Q) at (-4,-0.75);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (Q);
%Points P and Q are labeled.
\coordinate (label_for_P) at ($(P)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);
\node at (label_for_P){$P$};
\coordinate (label_for_Q) at ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(P)$);
\node at (label_for_Q){$Q$};

%Title for hexagon is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries,align=center,above=of F -| {$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$}] (title) {A set that is \\ not convex};


%A convex pentagon is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=6cm}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (O) at (-5,0);

\path[name path=x-axis] (A) -- (O);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_-1] (-5,-1) -- (0,-1);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_1] (-5,1) -- (0,1);

\coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (C') at ($(B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_BC] (B) -- (C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_BC and horizontal_line_at_-1, by={C}}];
\draw (B) -- (C);

\coordinate (D') at ($(C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_CD] (C) -- (D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_CD and x-axis, by={D}}];
\draw[dashed] (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E') at ($(D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_line_segment_DE] (D) -- (E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_line_segment_DE and horizontal_line_at_1, by={E}}];
\draw[dashed] (D) -- (E);

\draw (C) -- (E);

\coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (E) -- (F);
\draw (A) -- (F);

%Title for pentagon is typeset.
\node[font=\bfseries, above=of F -| {$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$} ] (title) {A convex set};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `scope` environment for the pentagon, the `F` is the highest vertex.  I had `E` in the command for placing the title.  Thanks for finding that mistake.  After the `tikzpicture` environment, I have the command `\hspace{\fill}`.  That should "balance" the `\noindent \hspace*{\fill}` before the `tikzpicture` environment.  It doesn't - not on my computer.

Comment: I am not familiar with the code for placing the title.  Does the option `node distance= 3mm and 0mm` for the `tikzpicture` environment only apply to nodes with `(title)` specified?  I think that the point `$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$` is determined using the `calc` package.  When I use such code for plotting points, I put it in a pair of parentheses - `($(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$)`.  I get an error when using it after `above=of`, though.

Comment: If I denote `$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$` by `M`, the code for placing the title for the convex set is `above=of F -| M`.  It seems precarious to me not to have either braces or parentheses enclosing `F -| M`.  I tried `above=of(F -| M)` and got an error. I enclosed it in braces and the code compiled.  If there is no space between the `of` and left brace, though, I get an error.  `above=of{F -| M}` does not compile.  What is the syntax for using `above=of` in a node?

Comment: @user74973 For node distances, see **Sec. 27.3, Padding and Node Distances** of the PGF manual. `above=of` needs the node name without parentheses. Or, in your case, the calculated node using the two dollars `$(C |- A)!0.5!(A)$`. It is Okay to use braces `{}` around a calculation `{$some formula$}`. See also **Sec. 13.5 Coordinate Calculations** of the documentation.

Comment: I have the link for "Padding and Node Distances" on my computer, and I will look at it later.  Do you know why the display is not centered horizontally on the page.  I have `\noindent\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tikzpicture} code for drawing hexagon and pentagon \end{tikzpicture}\hspace{\fill}`.

Comment: @user74973 A `tikzpicture` is normally encapsulated by a `figure` environment and centered inside that figure. It is not a wrapping inline object to fill line before or after it. I don't understand why you use `\hspace{fill}` here.

Comment: Most of the displays in my `LaTeX` files are centered via the way I suggested.  It is odd that this display is not.  I will use the command that centers it.  I have not used a `figure` environment.  Please tell me how to center the `tikzpicture` within it.

Comment: @user74973 Usually, we say `\begin{figure}[!htbp]\centering \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\end{figure}` to insert the picture into a figure and center it. Of course we get many advantages using the figure like cross referencing and captions, etc. In your example, this will fail, though, because of using the `transform canvas=` command which switches off tracking of the picture size. See page 363, **Sec. 25.4, Canvas Transformations** of the manual.

Comment: Do I omit `[!htbp]` since I will not be using for tracking?

Comment: `[!htbp]` are for figure placement here, top, bottom, or in separate page. What destroys picture size information is the `transform canvas=`, which will make centering too difficult. In cases like this, it's better to compile the picture as `standalone` and just include the output PDF file into the document inside your figure by `\begin{figure}[!htbp]\centering \includegraphics{file.pdf}\end{figure}`. Structured learning from books/manuals is best. Start learning the basics slowly and you will be able to draw any picture. Don't copy advanced (or poorly written) examples at first.

Comment: I would like to have all my coding done with only more familiar `TikZ` commands.  I posted code that horizontally centers the figures and that horizontally centers titles over the figures.  It is exactly what I want ... except the vertical spacing between the second figure and its title is less than the vertical spacing between the first figure and its title.  I specified `3mm` in each case, though.

Answer (score 0):

I want to center the figures horizontally on the page.  I prefer to do this with familiar commands in `TikZ`.  Here is code that gives the display that I want.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%A hexagon - a set that is not convex - is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (O) at (-5,0);

\path[name path=x-axis] (A) -- (O);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_-1] (-5,-1) -- (0,-1);
\path[name path=horizontal_line_at_1] (-5,1) -- (0,1);

\coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (C') at ($(B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_BC] (B) -- (C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_BC and horizontal_line_at_-1, by={C}}];
\draw (B) -- (C);

\coordinate (D') at ($(C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_CD] (C) -- (D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_CD and x-axis, by={D}}];
\draw (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E') at ($(D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_DE] (D) -- (E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_DE and horizontal_line_at_1, by={E}}];
\draw (D) -- (E);

\coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (E) -- (F);
\draw (A) -- (F);


%Points P and Q in the hexagon are plotted. Line segment $\overline{PQ}$ is not contained in the
%hexagon.
\coordinate (P) at (-4,0.75);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (Q) at (-4,-0.75);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (P) -- (Q);
%Points P and Q are labeled.
\coordinate (label_for_P) at ($(P)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);
\node at (label_for_P){$P$};
\coordinate (label_for_Q) at ($(Q)!-3mm!90:(P)$);
\node at (label_for_Q){$Q$};

%Title for hexagon is typeset.
%M_1 is the intersection of the vertical line through C and the horizontal line through A.
%It is on the x-axis and as far leftward as points C and E. M_2 is the midpoint of line
%segment AM_1. M_3 is the intersection of the vertical line through M_2 and the horizontal
%line through F.
\coordinate (M_1) at (C |- A);
\coordinate (M_2) at ($(M_1)!0.5!(A)$);
\coordinate (M_3) at (M_2 |- F);
\coordinate (title_for_hexagon) at ($(M_3)!-3mm!(M_2)$);
\node[font=\bfseries,anchor=south,inner sep=0,align=center] at (title_for_hexagon){A set that is \\ not convex};


%A convex pentagon is drawn which is symmetric across the x-axis.
\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_A) at (6,0);
\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_O) at (1,0);

\path[name path=rightward_shift_of_x-axis] (rightward_shift_of_A) -- (rightward_shift_of_O);
\path[name path=rightward_shift_of_horizontal_line_at_-1] (1,-1) -- (6,-1);
\path[name path=rightward_shift_of_horizontal_line_at_1] (1,1) -- (6,1);

\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_B) at ($(rightward_shift_of_A) + (-135:2.5)$);
\draw (rightward_shift_of_A) -- (rightward_shift_of_B);

\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_C') at ($(rightward_shift_of_B) + (165:3)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_BC] (rightward_shift_of_B) -- (rightward_shift_of_C');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_BC and rightward_shift_of_horizontal_line_at_-1, by={rightward_shift_of_C}}];
\draw (rightward_shift_of_B) -- (rightward_shift_of_C);

\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_D') at ($(rightward_shift_of_C) + (45:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_CD] (rightward_shift_of_C) -- (rightward_shift_of_D');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_CD and rightward_shift_of_x-axis, by={rightward_shift_of_D}}];
\draw[dashed] (rightward_shift_of_C) -- (rightward_shift_of_D);

\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_E') at ($(rightward_shift_of_D) + (135:2)$);
\path[name path=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_DE] (rightward_shift_of_D) -- (rightward_shift_of_E');
\coordinate[name intersections={of=extension_of_the_rightward_shift_of_DE and rightward_shift_of_horizontal_line_at_1, by={rightward_shift_of_E}}];
\draw[dashed] (rightward_shift_of_D) -- (rightward_shift_of_E);

\draw (rightward_shift_of_C) -- (rightward_shift_of_E);

\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_F) at ($(rightward_shift_of_E) + (15:3)$);
\draw (rightward_shift_of_E) -- (rightward_shift_of_F);
\draw (rightward_shift_of_A) -- (rightward_shift_of_F);

%Title for pentagon is typeset.
%rightward_shift_of_M_1 is the intersection of the vertical line through rightward_shift_of_C and
%the horizontal line through rightward_shift_of_A. It is on the x-axis and as far leftward as
%points rightward_shift_of_C and rightward_shift_of_E. rightward_shift_of_M_3 is the intersection
%of the vertical line through rightward_shift_of_M_2 and the horizontal line through
%rightward_shift_of_F.
\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_M_1) at (rightward_shift_of_C |- rightward_shift_of_A);
\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_M_2) at ($(rightward_shift_of_M_1)!0.5!(rightward_shift_of_A)$);
\coordinate (rightward_shift_of_M_3) at (rightward_shift_of_M_2 |- rightward_shift_of_F);
\coordinate (title_for_pentagon) at ($(rightward_shift_of_M_3)!-3mm!(rightward_shift_of_M_2)$);
\node[font=\bfseries,inner sep=0] at (title_for_pentagon){A convex set};

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```